# Checking profile fields are filled out

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a profile page that is pulling the logged in users details, I have stopped the password coming through. As i want them to re type it as part of their update of details.

What I want is to make sure they fill the fields and that the form cannot be updated with missing password or name etc.

```
<!-- loads the php file into here -->
<?php  

/* This script pulls the existing name input and displays it when the user logs in. */

session_start();

include("connection.php");

$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


?>


<Style>


.alert{
display:none;
}


</Style>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>profile</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/profilestyles.css">  

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">        </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


</head>



 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand">MyBday</a>

    </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">



           <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li role="presentation"><a href="mainpage.php">My connections</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">World connections</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"  class="active"><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>    
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php?logout=1">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>


            </form>

        </div>


</div>  
</div>


<div class="container">
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <!-- left column -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
      <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

      <input class="form-control" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- edit form column -->
  <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
      <strong>Profile updated.</strong>
    </div>
    <h3>Personal info</h3>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="edit_profile.php" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label name">name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
         <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" type="text" name="name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" type="text" name="email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">DOB:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['DOB'];?>" type="date" name="DOB">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>" type="text" name="country">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Re-enter password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="" placeholder="At least 8 characters and 1 cap letter" type="password" name="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="" placeholder="At least 8 characters and 1 cap letter" type="password" name="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit">
          <span></span>
          <input class="btn btn-default" id="updated" value="Cancel" type="reset">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

```
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

     $("#updated").click(function(){

  $(".alert").hide().show('medium');
});

     </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I have this script which i have copied from the login but not sure how i implement it into this profile page.

```
// check name is valid
    if (!$_POST['name']) $error.="<br />Please enter your name";


// check town is valid
//    if (!$_POST['town']) $error.="<br />Please enter your town/city.";

// check country is valid
    if (!$_POST['country']) $error.="<br />Please enter your country.";


// check DOB is valid
    if (!$_POST['DOB']) $error.="<br />Please enter your Date of birth.";        

// check email and password exist and are valid
    if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";

// if email exists check it is valid if not display error message
    if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
            else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))  $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email";

// password validation
    if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
    else { 

// if they have entered a password check how long it is
        if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br />please enter a password with at least 8 characters";

// check if it doesn't have a cap letter in it            
        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $_POST['password'])) $error.= "<br     />Please include min 1 capital letter in your password.";

            }

    if ($error) $error = "There were error(s) in your sign up details:".$error;
```

As I think is obvious to see php, sql is all new to me so trying my best to understand it all so be gentle and explain like I'm 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `required` to your input fields, and then they can't submit until they enter all values where you added `required`, more about required:

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

edit :

Checking with php would look like this :

```
/ check name is valid
if (!$_POST['name'] || $_POST['name']=="") $error.="<br />Please enter your name";
```

So just add to every field `|| $_POST['nameofinput']==""` and that is Server side checking + `required` from html

Comment: Sidenote: Server validation is still required to be done.

Comment: True, will edit answer and add server side checking.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, really appreciate it.